# how to get weather feeds for multiple cities in single request using yahoo weather api

Tags: weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

i am getting weather feeds from yahoo API ,but at a single request i able to get single place only .i want to get multiple cities feeds at a time in single request .
please help me to get multiple cities feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the web test platform they offer [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) you can test different YQL queries.

YQL is a SQL-like language and it supports operators like `OR` and `IN`.

My test concerning your question was this:

```
select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text in ("nome, ak", "chicago, il", "dallas, tx"))
```

This brings weather forecast for 3 cities.

Comment: How to get weather data for multipl lat longs, as I am trying with query but not able to get result "select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places WHERE text="(28.7041, 77.1025),(28.0229, 73.3119)")"

Comment: @AnandSuthar I guess you need an "or" in your query for the text. This for example works: `select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (SELECT woeid FROM geo.places WHERE text="(28.7041, 77.1025)" or text="(28.0229, 73.3119)")`